# Chandelier socket removal for arm replacement

Tags: socket

Hi I need to remove this light socket from a crystal chandelier I’m restoring. I need to replace one of the arms and I can’t seem to figure out how to get this weird screw loose. Everything I’ve looked up so far tells me to unscrew it but there isn’t a traditional screw it’s this weird Allan wrench shape on one side and completely smooth and flat on the other side. I hope I make sense. I need to fix this quick so any info would be greatly appreciated. [image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It looks like a rivet to me (i.e. not meant to be temporarily removed). And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1):

That bracket is riveted on. You could drill it out, but you'll have no good way to reattach it to a new socket anyway. Often candelabra sockets come with pre-attached brackets like that (sometimes threaded for a pipe nipple, other times slotted for a screw - hard to say which that is). Best option would be to remove the whole thing together if possible and try to find a matching one at the hardware store (I know my local store has a good variety of such sockets with attached brackets from Servalite). You shouldn't need to drill out the rivet to remove the wiring.

Answer (score 0):

That's a rivet, not a screw.
You'll have to drill the end off to get it out.

Comment: Gah! I knew it had a name lmao! Ok going. To try it now. Thank you!

Comment: Find the other end of that wire and  disconnect it there and pull it through. If you file off the rivet, You'll  have to replace the socket....

Answer (score 0):

That is a rivet, which was set in a rivet press at the factory which manufactured the socket.

The chandelier manufacturer bought these socket assemblies pre-made.  So clearly there's a way to disassemble it without disturbing the rivet.